# Multiple Hash Tags removal

Tags: php, regex

```
function getHashTagsFromString($str){
               $matches = array();
               $hashTag=array();
                    if (preg_match_all('/#([^\s]+)/', $str, $matches)) {

                        for($i=0;$i<sizeof($matches[1]);$i++){
                                $hashtag[$i]=$matches[1][$i];
                                }
                       return $hashtag;
                      }
            }

test string $str = "STR
this is a string
with a #tag and
another #hello #hello2 ##hello3   one
STR";
```

using above function i am getting answers but not able to remove two # tags from ##hello3 how to remove that using single regular expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your regular expression as follows:

```
/#+(\S+)/
```

**Explanation:**

- `/` - starting delimiter

  - `#+` - match the literal `#` character one or more times
  - `(\S+)` - match (and capture) any non-space character (shorthand for `[^\s]`)
- `/` - ending delimiter

[**Regex101 Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/nH1mS2)

The output will be as follows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => tag
    [1] => hello
    [2] => hello2
    [3] => hello3
)
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/101883)

Comment: Downvoter: Can you explain the downvote? It might help me improve the answer :)

Comment: +1 for a very good explanation and neutralizing the unnecessary downvote

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** To match all the hash tags use:

```
preg_match_all('/#\S+/', $str, $match);
```

To remove, instead of `preg_match_all` you should use `preg_replace` for replacement.

```
$repl = preg_replace('/#\S+/', '', $str);
```

Comment: i am finding hash tag and storing that string  in database. If i remove hash tag how to store string.

Comment: But your title said `Hash tag removal` I will edit now